# Java time, can't parse Year from Epoch Seconds

Tags: java, datetime, time, datetime-format, java-time

I am trying to parse `1523265822618` to A time String. However it does work for everything except the Year. Am I doing something wrong or is it Java which behaves strange?

```
long millis = job.lastBuild.timestamp * 1000
Date date = new Date(millis)
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.GERMANY);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
echo """${formattedDate}"""
>>> Samstag, 16 Mai, 50240 11:10:18

LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(job.lastBuild.timestamp, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC)
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, dd MMMM, yyyy, HH:mm:ss", Locale.GERMANY)
formattedDate = dateTime.format(formatter)
echo """${formattedDate}"""
>>> Samstag, 16 Mai, +50240, 11:10:18
```

The right Output would be `Samstag, 16 Mai, 2018, 11:10:18`

Sorry, the Error was 40cm away from the Screen, `job.lastBuild.timestamp` is already milliseconds thanks to MadProgrammer

Comment: Is `1523265822618` milliseconds? Nanoseconds? Seconds?

Comment: Seconds as you might can see when I calculate millis ;)

Comment: `LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(1523265822618L / 1000, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);` will result in `Monday, 09 April, 2018, 09:23:42` (sorry, dropped the locale)

Comment: So, the JavaDocs for `LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond` says *"epochSecond  the number of seconds from the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"* so you need to convert your "millisecond" value to "seconds", which would explain why my previous comment seems to work

Comment: You're the one unable to see that either your timestamp is indeed in seconds, and the correct date is indeed in the year 50240, or your expectation is wrong, the timestamp is in fact already in millis, and the actual date is a more reasonable April 9, 2018.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number you mention, 1523265822618, is already milliseconds. Your error is caused by multiplying by 1000. Just don’t do that.

```
    long millis = 1_523_265_822_618L;
    System.out.println(Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis));
```

> 2018-04-09T09:23:42.618Z

```
    System.out.println(Instant.ofEpochSecond(millis));
```

> +50240-05-16T11:10:18Z

PS Do yourself and those maintaining your code after you a favour: Don’t use the old, long outdated and troublesome classes `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `TimeZone`. Stick to java.time, the modern Java date and time API as in your second code snippet.

PPS For most purposes using a built-in format gives a more widely accepted result and is also easier, for example:

```
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.FULL)
                .withLocale(Locale.GERMANY);
        System.out.println(Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis)
                .atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"))
                .format(formatter));
```

> Montag, 9. April 2018 um 11:23:42 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `job.lastBuild.timestamp`. The following code works OK:

```
Date date = new Date(1523265822618L)

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.GERMANY);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
```

Result: Montag, 09 April, 2018 09:23:42

Comment: So the `L` is missing?

Comment: Check the value of `job.lastBuild.timestamp` it could be wrong or already millis value